# Shape Detection Using OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

- I am working on Image Processing and for that i am using OpenCV Library in c++.
- I have one image in which i want to detect particular shape and mainly want its point.
- I have below image , where four black corners are there.I want to detect four corner points as i have drawn with red color.[image]
- And please note that image can be at any angle or position. Not straight always.
- I have tried `cv::threshold`, `canny`, `findContours`, `minAreaRect` but I am not getting expected output.
- Please anybody can help me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has a [function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cornerharris#cornerharris) to detect corners using the Harris-Stephens method, [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html) is a tutorial with C++ code example.